# How to get average from set of objects in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, average

I have a simple rating system for a property. You give it a mark out of 5 (stars). The models are defined like this

```
def Property(models.Model)
    # stuff here

def Rating(models.Model)
    property = models.ForeignKey(Property)
    stars = models.IntegerField()
```

What I want to do is get a property, find all the Rating objects, collect them, then get the average 'stars' from them.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You should use [Aggregation(doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/):

```
from django.db.models import Avg

p = Property.objects.get(...)
stars_average = p.rating_set.aggregate(Avg('stars')).values()[0]
```

A little bit unsure about my example though.

Comment: Example was spot on :) Thank you very much drmegahertz.

Comment: For multiple properties in a single query you can use `Property.objects.annotate(Avg('rating__stars'))`

Comment: How to calculate average on `ratings = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(), blank=True,null=True)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [aggregate()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#aggregate) and [annotate()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.annotate) with [Avg()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#avg) to average the stars in `Rating` model and property by property as shown below. *I need to use `order_by('pk')` with `annotate()` otherwise values are printed in descending order:

```py
from django.db.models import Avg

# Average the stars in "Rating" model
print(Rating.objects.aggregate(Avg('stars'))) 

print()

# Average the stars in "Rating" model property by property
for obj in Property.objects.all(): 
    print(
        Rating.objects.filter(property=obj)
                      .aggregate(Avg('stars'))
    )

print()

# Average the stars in "Rating" model property by property
for obj in Property.objects.all(): 
    print(obj.rating_set.aggregate(Avg('stars')))

print()

# Average the stars in "Rating" model property by property
qs = Property.objects.annotate(Avg('rating__stars')).order_by('pk')
for obj in qs:
    print(obj.rating__stars__avg)
```

Then, these below are outputted on console:

```
{'stars__avg': 3.7}

{'stars__avg': 3.2}
{'stars__avg': 3.6}
{'stars__avg': 4.0}

{'stars__avg': 3.2}
{'stars__avg': 3.6}
{'stars__avg': 4.0}

3.2
3.6
4.0
```

And, you can change the default key `stars__avg` for **stars** column to `starsAvg` as shown below:

```py
from django.db.models import Avg

# Average the stars in "Rating" model
print(Rating.objects.aggregate(starsAvg=Avg('stars'))) 
                               # ↑ Here
print()

# Average the stars in "Rating" model property by property
for obj in Property.objects.all(): 
    print(
        Rating.objects.filter(property=obj)
                      .aggregate(starsAvg=Avg('stars'))
    )                            # ↑ Here

print()

# Average the stars in "Rating" model property by property
for obj in Property.objects.all(): 
    print(obj.rating_set.aggregate(starsAvg=Avg('stars')))
                                   # ↑ Here
print()

# Average the stars in "Rating" model property by property
qs = Property.objects.annotate(starsAvg=Avg('rating__stars')).order_by('pk')
for obj in qs:                 # ↑ Here
    print(obj.starsAvg)
              # ↑ Here
```

Then, the default key is changed as shown below:

```
{'starsAvg': 3.7}

{'starsAvg': 3.2}
{'starsAvg': 3.6}
{'starsAvg': 4.0}

{'starsAvg': 3.2}
{'starsAvg': 3.6}
{'starsAvg': 4.0}

3.2
3.6
4.0
```